# javascript define cookie

Tags: javascript

Something very wrong is going on this piece of code:

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie()
{
var username=getCookie("username");
if (username=="username"){
    document.getElementById(mydivx).style.display = 'block';  }else{
    document.getElementById(mydivx).style.display = 'none'; 
  }
}
```

and a button to define the cookie:

```
<a href="#" onClick="setCookie("username",username,365); return true">esconder</a>
```

So this should be happening, if the button is clicked, it defines a cookie named "username" with the value "username", the getcookie function gets the cookie username and its value.

What am i doing wrong?

Hope you can help me guys !

EDIT: SOLUTION:

Just remove the ";" from the call, and add some single quotations to the code from the button:

esconder

Thanks to stealthyninja

Comment: Avoid w3school see http://w3fools.com/ on why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML code, replace

```
<a href="#" onClick="setCookie("username",username,365); return true">esconder</a>
```

with

```
<a href="#" onClick="setCookie('username', 'username', 365); return false">esconder</a>
```

The `return false` is so that your browser doesn't actually browse to the `href` which would make a hash (`#`) appear in your address bar. In other words, it's similar to preventing the default action of clicking on the link without JavaScript to prevent it.

**Update**
The second `username` should be a variable or string. `username` by itself is undefined.

Comment: @stealthyninja, thank you for your contribution, i tried the modification you purposed an nothing changed, i think the rest of the code is working properly because if change both the display to block the bar will appear.

Comment: @Souza: If you mean changing `document.getElementById(mydivx).style.display = 'none';` to `document.getElementById(mydivx).style.display = 'block';` then, yes, it'll work because your code is failing on the `else` check. If you do an `alert('Username: ' + username);` after the `else` does it show `Username: ` or `Username: username`?

Comment: @stealthyninja, thank you so much for your patience. I tried what you said and the box prompted this message:
"Username: undefined"

Comment: @Souza: Ah, try `setCookie('username', 'username', 365)` in the link. The cookie was clearly not being set because the `username` you're trying to store isn't being defined anywhere.

Comment: @stealthyninja, i tried before what you said, but using the ";" at the end, and didn't work, what you purposed worked like a charm! Thank you very much!!  If you can edit your answer change onClick="setCookie('username', username,365);  to
onClick="setCookie('username', username,365)

Comment: Tried again with the ";" and it's making the difference, can't tell why :S

Answer (score 1):

your setcookie never got called I beleive try this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="setCookie('username',username,365); return true">esconder</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" onClick="setCookie("username",username,365); return true">esconder</a>
```

You have an error in that code. onClick="" and "username"... Try:

```
 <a href="#" onClick="setCookie('username','username',365);">esconder</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is all of it, but this line:

```
<a href="#" onClick="setCookie("username",username,365); return true">esconder</a>
```

Has a problem, since you're terminating the string. You're using double quotes inside double quotes; try

```
<a href="#" onClick="setCookie('username',username,365); return true">esconder</a>
```